# gender (french) for validation message on attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm using rails 3.0.9, and I'm trying to find elegant solution to translate validation messages on attributes (using I18n or something else). I would like to avoid using patching for every validation message in the Model. and I heard about the I18n inflector plugin, but it seems to be working for models only not for their attributes ([What is the best way to translate to a language with genders in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272933/what-is-the-best-way-to-translate-to-a-language-with-genders-in-rails))

Comment: So here is what you want probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451076/rails-internationalization-i18n-in-model-validations-possible-or-not

Comment: I don't think, it seems to be different. can you provide more accurate answer?